# Fit or predict function for LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to assign coordinates to a label based on that labels known coordinates using SciKit-learns Linear Discriminant Analysis package. Training coordinates and label stored in one pandas dataframe, target coordiantes in another. The two dataframes aren't equal in row length, training set is larger. I want to apply the label on the coordinates in the original dataframe to use as a key with pd.merge.

I know i could approach this problem using matplot point in polygon or Shapely but want to test it this way. Here's what i have based on the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis)

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
labels_fea = le.fit_transform(Spatial_index['Postcode']) 
trainingdata=df1[['xcoord','ycoord']].values
targetvalues=df2[['xcoord','ycoord']].values
clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(solver='svd', shrinkage=None, priors=None,      
n_components=None, store_covariance=False, tol=0.0001)
```

Then executed as below,

```
clf.fit(trainingdata,targetvalues)
```

This throws the following error,

```
ValueError: bad input shape (8860, 2)
```

Comment: can you include the line where you call `fit`?

Comment: thanks for looking max, have added that now

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused by target and test. The error is happening because the classifier expects a one-dimesional array of labels -- in your case, the postcodes. Without seeing your data I can't say for sure, but you probably want to do

```
clf.fit(trainingdata, labels_fea)
```

and then renaming `targetdata` to `testdata`, you would get your predictions to test your model with `clf.predict(testdata)`

Comment: Thanks max , I've made those adjustments.It churns away for along time (there are ~80k labels, whole of London) but then get the following error `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` i thought i could improve the match by adding another column of data common to both ('district') but it doesn't like the fact it's a str value. I'm not sure what happens behind the code but assumed this would help as the district limits the number of postcodes to 11,640 max.

Comment: it's too hard to say what's causing this without seeing the data, can you try and find a minimal subset of data where this error occurs ... do you get the error if you just restrict to the first few lines of your dataset?